# Best practice for optional date

Tags: usability, input-fields

The user must be able to set a date, in which case a certain event will happen on that date. Or don't set anything and the event won't happen. A couple of ideas:

[image]

I prefer **1** for compactness but I'm not sure it's clear when the checkbox is unchecked.

**3** I think it is the clearest but on the other hand it is very verbose and consumes a lot of space

windows setting solves the problem with **4**. clicking on the text description of the date opens a new ui (which I don't particularly like). the interesting thing is the toggles, that alongside have a description of the current state

[image]

Is there a best practice in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

I would pick 3. Is the clearest option.
Keep in mind that options 1 and 2 need the part with "The thing that has to happen"

Option 2 is a little bit confusing as the checkbox is inside the date selector and not close to the label.

Comment: yes, but as I said, it consumes a lot of screen real estate. moreover, dedicating so much space to this option seems to give it a higher importance than other options when in reality it is not true. there must be something equally clear but less verbose.

Comment: I would pick 3 too for you use case. I would pick 1 if this were a search among planned events, and the date were an optional criterion.